# Wordpress - Menu visibility error when a user is logged in or not

Tags: wordpress, webstore

I have a problem in my wordpress virtual store, in the main menu when you log in as a user you must deactivate the option to enter and register ... and show the user menu logged in as cart, orders, etc, this is duly configured in the appearance - menus option, but I can't understand why when I log in to the home page the menu keeps coming out as if the user was not logged in, but if I navigate to other pages like store, the mnu of logged in user, I appreciate some advice in advance, an additional fact is that I am using the Ultimate Member plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I could already find a solution, this error is removed by deactivating the woocommerce plugin, when the elementor panel is active changes are saved with the update button and then the woocommerce plugin is activated again and if we return to elementor the error already It is not presented, I suppose it is because in elementor there were some changes in draft and in some way it was related to the functioning of the woocommerce plugin.